# How to get the selection order in ag-Grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using the grid api to get the selected rows by using the function **`getSelectedRows()`**. However, the list of rows seems to be unordered, i.e the items are not in the order I selected them in.

Is there another way to get the selected rows in the order they were selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of the selected items yourself and make sure it's chronologically ordered by listening to `selectionChanged` event.

```js
// global keyboard state, put this outside of the function body
// we need to store the current shift key state to know if user
// are selecting multiple rows
const KEYBOARD_STATE = {
  isShiftPressed: false
};
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  KEYBOARD_STATE.isShiftPressed = e.key === "Shift";
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  KEYBOARD_STATE.isShiftPressed = false;
});
```

```js
const [selection, setSelection] = React.useState([]);
const onSelectionChanged = (e) => {
  const selectedNodes = e.api.getSelectedNodes();
  const lastSelectedNode =
    selectedNodes[0]?.selectionController?.lastSelectedNode;
  // if lastSelectedNode is missing while multi-selecting,
  // AgGrid will select from the first row
  const selectedNodeFrom = lastSelectedNode || e.api.getRenderedNodes()[0];
  const isRangeSelect = KEYBOARD_STATE.isShiftPressed;
  const difference = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.filter((x) => !arr2.includes(x));
  const newSelection = difference(selectedNodes, selection);

  if (newSelection.length > 0) {
    if (isRangeSelect) {
      const isSelectBackward =
        newSelection[0].rowIndex < selectedNodeFrom.rowIndex;

      if (isSelectBackward) {
        newSelection.reverse();
      }
    }

    newSelection.forEach((n) => updateSelection(n));
  } else {
    updateSelection(); // deselect
  }
};
```

```js
const updateSelection = (rowNode) => {
  setSelection((selections) => {
    if (rowNode) {
      const isSelected = rowNode.isSelected();

      if (isSelected) {
        return [...selections, rowNode];
      } else {
        return selections.filter((s) => s.id !== rowNode.id);
      }
    } else {
      return selections.filter((n) => n.isSelected());
    }
  });
};
```

```js
return (
  <>
    <pre>
      {JSON.stringify(selection.map((n) => n.data.id))}
    </pre>
    <AgGridReact
      rowSelection="multiple"
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      rowMultiSelectWithClick
      onSelectionChanged={onSelectionChanged}
      {...}
    />
  </>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 63988970/how-to-get-the-selection-order-in-ag-grid/63990845#63990845]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works well when multiple rows are selected by clicking or by using the ctrl-key. However, if I for instance, select a row at index 8, and then hold down the shift key and select a row at index 4, the selection will be: [8,4,5,6,7]. I was expecting: [8,7,6,5,4], since I started the selection on a higher index and ended the selection at a lower index. This is reproducible in your example. Do you know how to solve this particular problem?

Comment: @terjebra I've updated my answer and the demo to take into account of range selection.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly was I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome @terjebra. If you find this answer or any other answers helpful to you, please consider upvoting them. Thank you.